# Naming java objects

Tags: java, object, naming

So right now,  I am making a simple java banking program. It allows you to add a customer and deposit/withdraw funds. Right now, I have 3 classes: Main, Bank, and Customer. Right now I have it so that when you add a customer, it asks you for a name. But right now I am having trouble naming them. I want 
Customer to have a username as the object name. For example, if I typed in Bob1789 as the username, the program would do:

```
Customer Bob1789  = new Customer("Bob1789");
```

If I typed in randomcustomer123 the program would do:

```
Customer randomcustomer123 = new Customer("randomcustomer123");
```

So basically, whatever I type in the box from the scanner, to be passed to the Customer name.

```
Customer (whatever was typed in the scanner) = new Customer((whatever was typed in the scanner));
```

I have tried to do this, but java always assumes that the scanner.NextLine() is the Object name.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: name does not matter, its just a variable, what's important is the value of the class, if you have a name field in class then you can identify a customer using it

Comment: what's the use case of naming the variable ?

Comment: Heh. I knew where this was going just from the title. Seems like everyone wants to do this in some form as a beginner. Welcome to the world of data structures @SilentBeast! You will find many things to keep your interest fresh here.

Comment: Oh right, forgot naming the variable doesn't matter.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `HashMap<String, Customer>` for this. This allows you to store name-customer pairs.

```
HashMap<String, Customer> allCustomers = new HashMap<>();
```

To create a new customer and put it into the map,

```
String customerName = scanner.nextLine();
allCustomers.put(customerName, new Customer(customerName));
```

To get a customer with a specific name, use this:

```
allCustomers.get("some name");
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't know why you want to use obj name. Probably you need to use `HashMap<String, Customer>` where name is the key and value is the object.

```
Map<String, Customer> map = new HashMap<>();
```

to add `map.put("yourName", obj);`
to fetch `map.pget("yourName");`

Comment: Haven't learned HashMap yet, I am a Beginner in java, still learning the basics. Thanks for the help though!